# Stored Procedure doesn't exist, or does it?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm having a problem:

I have a db connection where I run stored procedures on. This same connection is used to create said stored procedures earlier on.

When I attempt to call a given stored procedure, later on, I get the following message:

> Could not find stored procedure
>   'dbo.yaf_prov_upgrade'.

The problem is it actually does exist on the database. And there's also the fact that it shows up on the SQL Server Profiler.

> RPC:Completed exec
>   [dbo].[yaf_prov_upgrade]
>   @PreviousVersion=46,@NewVersion=46    .Net
>   SqlClient Data
>   Provider  Nico    Matrix\Nico

I was wondering what could be the causes a particular query would throw such an exception even when it exists, it's called, and the call reaches the database.

It can't be a problem with the connection because it already executed other stored procedures. It can't be a problem with the procedure because it does exist, in fact the very same application, the very same web page, created it and put it there.

Update: forgot to mention I'm used integrated security, and I did run the SP on the database with the same user the application connects with, and I had no problem running it.

So what *can* it be?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your RPC completed only means that the batch submitted to SQL Server was correct and completed. It doesn't mean the stored procedure ran and executed OK.

It *will* be (don't argue, check) one of:

- wrong permissions
- wrong database context
- wrong server
- stored proc is in a different database

To *ensure* that things are the same

```
SELECT
   @@SERVERNAME, 
   SUSER_SNAME(), 
   DB_NAME(), 
   USER_NAME(), 
   OBJECT_ID('dbo.yaf_prov_upgrade')
```

The OBJECT_ID will be NULL if the stored proc doesn't exist *in that database* or you don't have permissions.

Comment: Hmm the problem was I was using two databases, one for membership and the other for the forums, I merged them and it worked, I didn't get to test your query but I'll assume you're right

Comment: @Nico: kinda thing that happens to us all now and then. No need to run the query now you've identified "wrong database context"

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it might be a permissions issue, check up if the user name your program is executing under has execute rights to the stored proc.

Comment: Yes, I think this might be the issue too. But I can't see how, I'm using integrated security, and everything is local, and I checked, I do have enough permission to execute the proc myself.

Comment: Just double check if your program user name has run rights i..e do not assume the program is using same username as your login name etc. Usually is something very simple and silly...face-meet-palm errors in such situations.

Comment: I'm using integrated security, this means the user that connects is the user that's logged in my computer, which is the same login I use on the db. The connection string is `<add name="yafnet" connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=dnforum;Integrated Security=True" />`

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert by far on ms-sql, but I do know it keeps SPs in a global cache.  Is it possible the local connection only gets the global list of SPs upon connection?  Maybe reinit the connection or re-select the cache?

Comment: What do you mean re-init the connection? I tried this quite a couple of times, the connection has been restarted various times.

Comment: Ya that's what I meant. Again, not much knowledge of C#, I'm more of a php/mysql kind of guy, but it looks like you are calling a database object and then an SP name.  Is that right?

Do C# db object need the database reference in front on the SP name?  So like dbo.databasename.spname